# Is there an English translation of Shri Vidyaranya's Sarva darshana sangraha online?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, book-recommendation, shad-darshana

I know that there is a Sanskrit version of this book, which seems to cover all philosophy of the Indian subcontinent.

So if any of you have the link to the English version online please post it here.

Answer (score 4):

**Sanskrit version:**

1. [Shri Madhavacharya (Shri Vidyaranya) virachitha Sarva darshana Sangraha, edited by Panditha Ishwara chandra
   Vidyasagara](https://archive.org/details/SarvaDarsanaSangrahaIsvarachandraVidyasagara1858bis_201804)
2. [Shri Madhavacharya (Shri Vidyaranya) virachitha Sarva darshana Sangraha, with Madhusudhana Saraswathi's
   Prasthanabhedha, Anandashrama publications](https://archive.org/details/SarvaDarshanSangrahaMadhavacharya)
3. [Shri Madhavacharya (Shri Vidyaranya) virachitha Sarva darshana Sangraha, with Abhyankaropaahva Vasudevashastri's
   Commentary](https://archive.org/details/Sarva-darsana-sangrahaOfMadhavacharya)

---

**English translations:**

1. Shri Madhavacharya (Shri Vidyaranya) virachitha Sarva darshana Sangraha by E.B.Cowell and A.E.Gough:

- a. [First Edition - 1882](https://archive.org/details/sarvadarsanasamg035018mbp)
- b. [Second Edition - 1894](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.8892)
- c. [Fourth Edition - 1904 (Popular Reissue - 1914)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.222721)
- d. [Sixth Edition - 1961](https://archive.org/details/198026072SarvaDarshanSangrahaOfMadhavacharyaEngTranslationEBCowellAndAEGough)
- e. [Seventh Edition - 1978](https://archive.org/details/SarvaDarshanSangrahaCowellAndGough)
- f. [Latest Edition - 1987](https://archive.org/details/06zSarvaDarsanaSamgrahaTransCosmoPub)

---

2. [Shri Madhavacharya (Shri Vidyaranya) virachitha  Sarva darshana Sangraha 16th Chapter by Klaus K. Klostermaier, First Edition - 1999](https://archive.org/details/SarvaDarsanaSangrahaOfMadhvacharyaKlausKlostermaierK.AdyarLibrary)
   The 16th chapter dealing with Shankara Darshana (Advaitha Vedanta), is missing in the popular version, so this book deals only with the 16th chapter.